# Try to run the azure-iot-sdk-java provisioning-x509-sample with an own x509-certificate

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I'm trying to run the azure-iot-sdk-java provisioning-X509-sample.

What I do jet is, I have create a certificate-chain with openssl and generate a X509-certificat. I uploaded this certificate to the azure DPS.
I check the fingerprint of the uploaded cert and all looks fine.

In a next step I configure the ProvisioningX509Sample.java. Enter the idScope, globalEndpoint and as the leafPublicPem I enter the Base64 String

```
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" + "\n" +
************ + "\n" +
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
```

Also as the leafPrivateKey I enter the Private Key of my intermediate-ca which create/sign my X509-Device-certifivate

```
"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" + "\n" +
************+ "\n" +
"-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
```

As transport-protocol i will use MQTT

If I run this sample I get the following error(s)

```
Starting...
Beginning setup.
Waiting for Provisioning Service to register
com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.provisioning.device.internal.exceptions.ProvisioningDeviceConnectionException: Exception opening connection amqp
        at com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.provisioning.device.internal.contract.mqtt.ContractAPIMqtt.open(ContractAPIMqtt.java:142)
        at com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.provisioning.device.internal.task.ProvisioningTask.call(ProvisioningTask.java:267)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to connect to mqtt service
        at com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.deps.transport.mqtt.MqttConnection.connect(MqttConnection.java:151)
        at com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.provisioning.device.internal.contract.mqtt.ContractAPIMqtt.open(ContractAPIMqtt.java:135)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: MqttException (0) - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:715)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1002)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(SSLSocketImpl.java:1779)
        at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(HandshakeOutStream.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.sendChangeCipherSpec(Handshaker.java:1156)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.sendChangeCipherAndFinish(ClientHandshaker.java:1267)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:1179)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:348)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1052)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:987)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.SSLNetworkModule.start(SSLNetworkModule.java:108)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:701)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
        ... 21 more
Registration error, bailing out
Press any key to exit...
```

I don't understand this error. Is there another step missing?

thanks for help and best regards

JensV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DPS only supports TLS 1.2. TLS connections from older versions will be rejected.